# Understanding some details of " The Simple Approximation Theorem " proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, definition

The theorem and its proof (from Royden " Real Analysis " forth edition ) is shown below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**My questions are:**

$1$-In case($1$), I do not understand why what is written leads to $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \psi_{n}(x) = f(x).$$ Could anyone explain this for me please?

$2$-In case($2$), why when $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi_{n}(x) = f(x)$ this leads to that the sequence $\{ \psi_{n}\}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $E.$Could anyone explain this for me please?

$3$-where is the proof of $|\phi_{n}| \leq |f|$ on $E$ for all $n$?

$4$-Why if we replace each $\phi_{n}$ with max $\{ \phi_{1}, ..., \phi_{n}\}$, we will have $\{\phi_{n}\}$ increasing?

Could anyone explain all the above points for me please?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. What do you know about $\psi_n - f$ according to the construction? /// 2. $\psi_n  \geqslant \varphi_n$, if $\varphi_n \to \infty$, what about $\psi_n$? /// 3. Problem 23. /// 4. What is the definition of "increasing sequence"?

Comment: For your first question $(\psi_{n} - f) \geq 0$

Comment: Your answer for me for my second question made me understand  the answer to my question. @xbh

Comment: And your answer for my third question is okay for me @xbh

Comment: So the discrepancies for me now are only the first and the fourth question @xbh ..... could you help me in those please?